# How to get search_key in VLOOKUP for month/year from month/day/year cells

Tags: date, google-sheets

I'm working in Google Spreadsheets/Forms which transfer data from Form to Spreadsheet. In one of Cells I need to transfer comment which is text value for a given month. My function looks like this:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('Forms of X'!$C:$C,">="&H$1,'Forms of X'!$C:$C,"<="&EOMONTH(H$1,0)), VLOOKUP(MONTH('Forms of X'!$C:$C)=MONTH(H$1)&YEAR('Forms of X'!$C:$C)=YEAR(H$1), 'Forms of X'!$C:$P, 14, 0))
```

So, in 'Forms of X' sheet i get responses from Forms.

C column is Date in mm/dd/yyyy format.
P column is text message (comment) from a form.

In my main spreadsheet i get values from 'Forms of X' sheet, where i need to get comments aswell. Here H1 cell is e.g. November2015 (11/1/2015). I can't get proper search_key for VLOOKUP to search for 11/2015 in C column of 'Forms of X' sheet. I presume it's simple to get but I don't have much time to get this done. Could anyone possibly help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vlookup portion of your formula should look like this:

`VLOOKUP(MONTH(H$1)&"/" &(H$1), 'Forms of X'!$C:$P, 14, 0)`

In your formula, you test for conditions in the `search_key` argument of the `vlookup`, which is invalid. You also left out the "/" between month and year.

Comment: Apparently it didn't work for me. Did I even get the correct function to transfer comments for my main sheet? Or do you have any other idea how could I do it? for e.g. X user sets 11/30/2015 date in C column with comment 'asd' in P column. I just need to transfer comment from 'Forms of x' sheet to proper cell by the date (month/year), which is in H1 cell.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the function is working for me if I set it to

```
=VLOOKUP(H$1, 'Forms of X'!$C:$P, 14, 0)
```

and comment is correctly displayed when day of respond is 11/1/2015. My problem is that the day won't always be 1st (as 11/1/2015 in H1 Cell), so I need to get the comment by month and year only.

So if someone responds 11/5/2015 the function is not working as H1 is 11/1/2015. I need to get the comment if it has been responded for any day of 11/2015.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet so we can have a look ?

Comment: Actually i figured it myself. My code just had to look like this (if someone is interested): `VLOOKUP(EOMONTH(H$1,0), 'Forms of X'!$C:$P, 14, true)`. Thanks for responding tho!